# Method is not being called, but is defined in controller and model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method to toggle a user between admin or not-admin. When I click the link I am placed back in the User index with the following in my address bar:  `http://localhost:3000/users?id=1&method=toggle_admin`. As far as I can tell, I have the appropriate code to run the method.  Can anyone see a mistake?

Here's the view link_to method:

```
<%= link_to 'Toggle Admin', { :controller => :users, :method => :toggle_admin, :id => user.id} %>
```

Here's the routes.rb statement:

```
match 'users/:id/toggle_admin' => 'users#toggle_admin'
```

The controller method:

```
def toggle_admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    User.toggle_admin(@user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @users }
    end

end
```

The model method:

```
def toggle_admin(user)
  if user.is_admin.nil or user.is_admin = ''
     user.is_admin = false
  end
  user.toggle is_admin

  user.save
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying using `:action` instead of `:method`. `:method` should be used with HTTP verb (i.e GET, PUT and so on)

```
<%= link_to 'Toggle Admin', { :controller => :users, :action => :toggle_admin, :id => user.id} %>
```